# Append Values to JSON object in SQL 2016 / Modify JSON object (SQL Server JSON Data)

Tags: sql-server, json, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016, sql-server-json

I have a JSON column in SQL2016 database, and I want to add a key-value pair to the root of the JSON object.

The content of the JSON column should be altered from

`{"Info1":"Value1"}`

to

`{"Info1":"Value1", "Info2":"Value2"}`

Answer (score 4):

With SQL Server 2016, it can be done using the built-in functions to manipulate JSON data. The following function will return the modified JSON data:

```
JSON_MODIFY(JsonColumn, '$.Info2', 'Value2')
```

The expression can be used in normal `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET JsonColumn = JSON_MODIFY(JsonColumn, '$.Info2', 'Value2')
```

The `NULL` values in `JsonColumn` will be updated to  `{ "Info2":"Value2"}`.

If `JsonColumn` contains another value for `Info2` key, it will be overwritten.

Comment: why do we need coalesce  and {} ?